# Captcha on nginx server, brute-force attack

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, ddos, synology

I have a server Synology DSM 6.2 NGINX and WordPress web site on it. Web site is hosted on port :80, server page is hosted on port :5000.

Someone is trying to hack the admin server account by accessing the login screen on port :5000, something like brute-force attack.

I want to set captcha like on Cloudflare on this login page, but I don't have access to this login page code, so I can't put Google ReCaptcha scripts into the header for example.

So the question is, is it possible to create some kinda redirect logic in NGINX like: "when user trying to access port :5000 check cookies for a token, if token not found, redirect or show(somehow) captcha, if verification succeeds, redirect back to the port :5000"?

Maybe there is some kind of plugin or better way to solve this problem?

PS Sorry for the poor English and incomprehensible explanations.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look to fail2ban. It checks logs and update firewall rules following certain scenario.
Basically, it can ban an ip after x failed login

A bit old but may still be useful : http://www.iholken.com/index.php/2016/07/22/guide-for-installing-fail2ban-for-synology-nas-devices-and-configuring-it-for-web-services-like-owncloud-or-wordpress/

Comment: @Will, I thought about that, but it kind a useless, I have already set up user baning in system settings after 2 failed logins, it's not helping, each login attempt coming from different IP

Comment: What about changing from port 5000 (standard one for login I guess) to an other one ? And you can have a page on 5000 which shows a captcha and then send you on the right port if you think that's necessary. IMO changing the port may be enough to stop the attack

Comment: @Will, redirect from page with captcha to the new port is not the best solution, because hacker can bypass captcha by himself and he will be redirected to the new page with a new port, so the attack will continue. Changing the port I think the best solution here.

Comment: I think this is a bot, and whoever runs it won't come and resolve any captcha by himself but technically you're right

Comment: It can be done, but the setup is a bit complicated.  You might want to have a look at this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-bandwidth-limits-nginx-plus-key-value-store/#Complete-Sample-NGINX-Configuratio

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options:

1. change to https (mandatory)
2. activate IP blocking for attacks and expand to whole ranges where necessary
3. Install Zyxel USG and add rules to block geography

I have sometimes 6-7 attacks per second and at least 1-2 per minute. Firewall blocks almost everything. If you don't need access to your site from Russia, China, Ukraine, etc, then this is the most effective way.